# Feasible way to do automated performance testing on various database technologies?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, relational-database

A lot of guys on this site state that: "Optimizing something for performance is the root of all evil". My problem now is that I have a lot of complex SQL queries, many of them utilizing user created functions in PL/pgSQL or PL/python. My problem is that I do not have any performance profiling tool to show me, which functions actually make the queries slow. My current method is to exclude the various functions and take the time on the query for each one. I know that I could use explain analyze as well, but I do not think it will provide me with the information about user created functions.

My current method is quite tedious, especially since there is not query progress in PostgreSQL so I have sometimes have to wait for the query to run for 60 seconds, if I choose to run it on too much data.

Therefore, I am thinking whether it could be a good idea to create a tool, which will automatically do a performance profiling of SQL queries by modifying the SQL query and take the actual processing time on various versions of it. Each version would be a simplified one, which would maybe just contain a single user created function. I know that I am not describing how to do this clearly, and I can think of a lot of complicating factors, but I can also see that there are workarounds for many of these factors. I basically need your gut feeling on whether such a method is feasible.

Another similar idea is to run the query setting server settings work_mem to various values, and showing how this would impact the performance.

Such a tool could be written using JDBC so it could be modified to work across all major databases. In this case it might be a viable commercial product.

Comment: Actually, we quote Don Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." The underlying ideas: 1) Make it right before you make it faster. 2) Keep it right when making it faster. 3) Know when to stop making it faster. I'm not sure where I learned those three--maybe _Elements of Programming Style_ by Kernighan and Plauger.

Answer (score 1):

Apache JMeter can be used to load test and monitor the performance of SQL Queries (using JDBC). It will howerever not modify your SQL.

Actually I don't think **any** tool out there could simplify and then re-run your SQL. How should that "simplifying" work?

Comment: I have not figured out the details on the simplifying, but one way could be to reduce the number of selected columns. A different way could be to replace any user built function with a dummy value (varchar if that is returned from the function, integer if that is returned). Maybe one could simplify it by removing a left join. Someone smart needs to think carefully about this.